# Visual Studio 2010. Hilight C# Code for buttons, menu etc in the designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, menu, interface

I'll try to explain as best I can. I'm looking at some old C# code (not code I wrote). I am having difficulty with reading the parts of the code related to user interface.

So my question is, what (if any) tools are there to highlight code (in the code view) that reflect the visual representations. For example if I were to create a text block and I wanted to display Hello World, I'd write something like `textBlock.Text = "hello World";` Is there anyway to highlight text like that (Hello world already is of course) in a similar way to e.g. classes and literal strings?

Clarification: The base code is easily transferable, the functions are simple and should port easily, Howe ever the user interface will change completely so what I want to do is either separate OR easily recognise the user interface code from the rest of the application.

Comment: To clarify if I understood your question correctly: So you are looking for something like a code-editor control?

Comment: Ctrl + F? I don't understand what you are attempting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but:

**To Find Results**

1. Ctrl + F (Search and find) - very basic
2. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/18fc5767-d3e6-4483-adbd-7396b0ea164e/ - Plug-in results finder for vs2010, this shows all results in one screen too.
3. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cfdf85c2-aaa4-4bdd-b8ea-e22bcc9860af - a Class finder plug-in
4. There might be more over at [Nuget](http://nuget.codeplex.com/), might be work taking a look.

Comment: Thank you those tools were helpful.